# Integer Programming (non $0-1$) Reduction to show $NP$ Completeness

Tags: integer-programming, np-complete, satisfiability

I'm having trouble coming up with a reduction for the integer programming problem when the variables aren't constrained to $0$ or $1$. For the case where the variables are constrained to $0$ or $1$, we can use 3SAT to show that IntProg is $NP$-complete. We simply have a clause for each equation which is in the form of $x1 + x2 + x3 <= 1$

If we allow the variables to be just any integer, then could a valid way to use 3SAT be to map integers $<= 0$ to $0$, and $>= 1$ to $1$? Or Is there another reduction I am overlooking?

Comment: Since 0-1 ILP is NP-complete and 0-1 ILP is a special case of ILP, the latter, which is in NP, is also NP-complete.  Also note that the translation of clause $x_1 \vee \neg x_2 \vee x_3$ produces the linear constraint $x_1 + (1 - x_2) + x_3 \geq 1$ or, equivalently, $x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \geq 0$.  You write a linear constraint for each clause, not the other way around.